# C# Add Checkbox To WinForms Context Menu

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes on a form.
I want to be able to select these from a context menu as well as the form itself. The context menu is linked to the system tray icon of the application.

My question is, is it possible to link the context menu to these checkboxes?
Or even possible to add checkboxes to the context menu?
Or even a combination?!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The menu items have a `Checked` property ([`MenuItem.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.checked.aspx), [`ToolStripMenuItem.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.checked.aspx)) that you can use for this purpose.

Regarding the possibility to link the context menu items to the check boxes, if you use a `ContextMenuStrip` and set `CheckOnClick` property to `true`, you can hook up the `CheckedChanged` events to the same event handler for the `ToolStripMenuItem` and `CheckBox` controls that should be "linked", and inside that event handler make sure to synchronize the `Checked` property of the controls and perform any other needed actions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a menu item has the "Checked" property, which can make it behave like a checkbox. When you click a menu item, you can programmatically toggle the state of the corresponding checkbox on your form.

You can also use the Opening event of the context menu to set the Checked state of the menu items based on the checked state of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can host standard as well as custom controls by wrapping them in a ToolStripControlHost

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
  //Create the combo box object and set its properties
  cmbFunctionArea               = new ComboBox();
  cmbFunctionArea.Cursor        = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
  cmbFunctionArea.DropDownStyle=System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
  cmbFunctionArea.Dock          = DockStyle.Fill;
  //Event that will be fired when selected index in the combo box is changed
  cmbFunctionArea.SelectionChangeCommitted += new   EventHandlercmbFunctionArea_SelectedIndexChanged);
```