# Show checkbox for Context MenuStrip or Context Menu of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

I am designing a logging feature in which User can select which event he wants to log.
On clicking button, I am showing such type of menu:
[image: Context Menu on Button click]

User can select multiple Events so I need to show "Check Mark" infront of the selected option when user clicks on it.

I am unable to find any options like "Checked" or "CheckOnClick" as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069687/c-sharp-add-checkbox-to-winforms-context-menu).

I tried with ContextMenu and ContextMenuStrips but couldn't achieve Checkboxes.
Any Suggestions??

Comment: If my answer assisted you, would you please be so kind as to accept it as the correct answer for future vistors.  Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't see any of your code so I don't know how you create this menu.  But in the most general terms, here is how you access the `Checked` property.

```
((ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items[0]).Checked = true; //false;
((ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items[1]).Checked = true; //false;
((ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items[2]).Checked = true; //false;
```

You can assign them as either true or false.  If you have named your `ToolStripItems`, then you can access them directly rather than going to the `Items` array.

```
contextMenuStrip.event1.Checked = true; //false;
```

As you can see, I am using a `ContextMenuStrip`.

Comment: But its not looks like checkbox in the UI ?! only act like ?

Comment: I will add that ShowCheckMargin property must be set to true, like the answer below says.

Answer (score 7):

Change the property **CheckOnClick** to **True**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In order for this to work visually, you need to ensure the "ShowCheckMargin" property is ON.  Otherwise the ".Checked" property will silently do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

While you could use:

```
((ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items[0]).Checked = true; //false;
```

this can be dangerous because at a later date you might reorder your menu items and then the code won't match.

Instead, in the **designer** click on the menu then the item (like Event1) to see the properties and set the item **Modifiers** to **Public** or **Internal**. Then in your code you can type the name of the item and set the check:

```
event1_ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true; //false;
```

Note: you don't need to type name of the contet menu strip. Just the item name.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see a checkmark but a focus rectangle partially overlapping the ToolStripMenuItem Text, then setting ImageScaling to None might help (in my case what seemed to be the focus rectangle was actually a very wide checkmark overlapping the text).

Answer (score 0):

you might need to set the Checked property in Opening event.